# Getting incorrect instances count via LaunchTime in Powershell

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am getting the incorrect instances count via LaunchTime while using Powershell, any idea of improvement here
Here is my snippets to fetch the instances details which were created in last 2 Days:

```
    $getDays = Get-Date
    $2Days = $getDays.AddDays(-2).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
    Write-Output ("LaunchTime: " +$2Days)
    $instancesCreated = aws ec2 --profile $awsProfile --region $awsRegion describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,LaunchTime>='$2Days']"
    Write-Output ($instancesCreated)
```

Any input or recommendation on this